# How can I get pixel-wise object dependencies in Unity 3D?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm developing autonomous car simulator. I have well-designed open source SW for doing it and want to customize this program to meet my needs. I'm studying deep learning models, but It is first time to use graphics tool like Unity 3D.

While I'm collecting training datasets for machine learning algorithms, I split a game playing video into many frames(screen shots) and feed these frames for my deep learning model as inputs. In this process, I want to know the object labels in pixel-by-pixel manner. For example, like image segmentation, I want to know which pixels belong to road, wall or any drivable object. I think that this information can be derivable in Unity 3D, because we created map first!!

Is there any hints for this problem?

Thank you in advance!!

Comment: You need to use OpenCV in Unity to train images then it will be possible to do [this](http://vladlen.info/publications/feature-space-optimization-for-semantic-video-segmentation/)

Comment: To Programmer:: I have used python based deep learning model already. As you thought, I can do segment images by using OpenCV. But it can't be actual ground truth. I need precise ground truth extracted from real object model in unity 3d.

Comment: You have to use C++ based if you want to to work on most platforms other go with python for desktop platforms only

Comment: I developed interface between this program and my python model already. It receives and transmit the controls(direction, velocity etc..) and images in realtime. But I want it to transmit segmented image by unity level processing for more precise result and availability.

Comment: You didn't mention these in your question. What's your current question?

Comment: I want to segment each frames precisely in unity!! It's my falut. : )

Answer (score 0):

Within Unity you can create tags, and tag various things.  For example in an `onTriggerEnter` for a Collider you might check to see what ran into it with `.CompareTag(tag)` like so.

```
void OnTriggerEnter(Collider Col){

    if(Col.CompareTag("Player")&&isActive){

        GetComponent<AudioSource>().Play();
        Player.gotCoin();

        isActive=false;

    }
}
```

Comment: Can I get the Image like below? [link](http://vladlen.info/publications/feature-space-optimization-for-semantic-video-segmentation/)